# Why won't my high score save?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, store

I genuinely cannot figure out why my high score will not save. To preface this, here is the general task that I am trying to accomplish.

- If score is greater than high score, high score will become score.
- If the user exits the app, the high score data will persist.
- Display the high score on the screen when the user fails the game.

Here is the relevant code.

In implementation:

```
int highScore;
NSUserDefaults * defaults;
```

In initialize:

```
 defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

In main body of code:

```
 scoreLabelNumber = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:myScore fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:25.0f];
scoreLabelNumber.color = [CCColor whiteColor];
scoreLabelNumber.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width / 2 + 35, self.contentSize.height - 95);

if(alive == FALSE){

    if(score > highScore){

        highScore = score;

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:score forKey:@"highscrore"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    }

}
```

The high score will show up, but if I exit the app no information regarding this high score is saved. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you "forgot" to load the value back into your highScore variable:

```
highScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"highscrore"];
```

Note that this:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:score forKey:@"highscrore"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Can be shortened to this:

```
    [defaults setInteger:score forKey:@"highscrore"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

And you might want to fix the @"highscrore" typo.